# Can I apply for a new long-term visit visa to the UK before my current visa expires?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas, repeat-visits

My current visa expires in August 2018 and I want to travel from July to September 2018 due to a family event. I have been travelling frequently to the UK and have never overstayed.

Comment: When was your existing long-term Standard Visitor Visa granted and how much time have you spent in the U.K. using your current visa in total and in the last 12 months (including the proposed visit)?

Comment: My existing 5 year visa was granted in 2013 and expiring in Aug 2018. I have hardly made 3 visits and spent a maximum of 2 months in total from these 3 visits. I stayed for about 3 weeks in my only visit in the last 12 months. I am only visiting my immediate family and have a family event for which I have to stay from mid July '18 upto early September '18 (about 6 weeks) which are dates on two sides of my current visa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I have done so myself. I had  2 months of visa remaining. The new visa was issued without a problem.

Comment: Yes I got mine as well. You just have to explain your situation in the additional information section when filling up the online form. I got my new visa before the old one was expiring and travelled successfully without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply to extend your existing visa for up to 6 months, providing you continue to meet the rules https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673351/Visit-guidance-v7.0EXT.PDF#page36 There’s nothing in the guidance that precludes a renewal application whilst an existing visa is still valid.

Comment: I checked that option, but turns out it costs almost 1000GBP to extend it for 6 months while I can spend almost the same amound to get a new 10year visa instead. Hence, I wanted to know if I can apply for a new visa starting from July '18 even though I have my current visa which will expire in Aug '18.